# How can I run du command from a file on RHEL when file has directories with spaces in the names?

Tags: xargs, rhel7, du

On linux, I have a file called dirs.txt.  This file has directory names in it, some of which contain embedded blanks.  I want to run the du -sh command on each directory name (to get a total usage for each directory and its children).  I've tried:

```
cat dirs.txt | xargs du -sh
```

but that seems to split the directory names on their spaces which means lots of errors.  How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat dirs.txt | tr '\12' '\0' | xargs -0 du -sh
```

So long as the `dirs.txt` file has one directory name per line, this works.

- The tr command changes the returns (\12) to be nulls (\0).
- Then run `xargs` with the `-0` option to take care to not mishandle special characters like spaces.